# How to design database for round-robin tournament

Tags: sql

I am developing round robin tournament and I have problem how to design database.

First I have season. Season contains list of tournament. Tournaments contains list of groups. Groups contains list participant. Then I have list of player. Different between player and participant is that participant is registered player which belongs to group. Then I have entity game which is defined by 2 participant and their score. So participant has list of games.

P = participant
G = game

```
   P1 P2 P3
P1 X  G1 G2
P2 G3 X  G4
P3 G5 G6 X
```

Is this good model for my tournament ? I dont think so because I have duplicity in my db. G1 is just vice versa of G3 but I have no idea how to implement this model better

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `GAME`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GAME` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AWAY_PARTICIPANT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `HOME_SCORE` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AWAY_SCORE` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID` (`HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID`),
  KEY `AWAY_PARTICIPANT_ID` (`AWAY_PARTICIPANT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `GROUPS`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GROUPS` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `TOURNAMENT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `NAME` (`NAME`,`TOURNAMENT_ID`),
  KEY `TOURNAMENT_ID` (`TOURNAMENT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `PLAYER`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PLAYER` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `SURNAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `CLUB` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `PARTICIPANT`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PARTICIPANT` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `POINTS` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `RANK` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PLAYER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SCORE` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0:0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `PLAYER_ID` (`PLAYER_ID`),
  KEY `GROUP_ID` (`GROUP_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ; 


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `SEASON`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SEASON` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `TOURNAMENT`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TOURNAMENT` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `SEASON_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `SEASON_ID` (`SEASON_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;    


--
-- Constraints for table `GAME`
--
ALTER TABLE `GAME`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `GAME_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`HOME_PARTICIPANT_ID`) REFERENCES `PARTICIPANT` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `GAME_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`AWAY_PARTICIPANT_ID`) REFERENCES `PARTICIPANT` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `GROUPS`
--
ALTER TABLE `GROUPS`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `GROUPS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`TOURNAMENT_ID`) REFERENCES `TOURNAMENT` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;  


--
-- Constraints for table `PARTICIPANT`
--
ALTER TABLE `PARTICIPANT`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PARTICIPANT_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`GROUP_ID`) REFERENCES `GROUPS` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PARTICIPANT_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`PLAYER_ID`) REFERENCES `PLAYER` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;    


--
-- Constraints for table `TOURNAMENT`
--
ALTER TABLE `TOURNAMENT`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `TOURNAMENT_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SEASON_ID`) REFERENCES `SEASON` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you say you have duplicity then you need re-visit your design. Have you ever used Enhanced relationship diagrams? This is a good tool to make sure you have a correct database design for you.

This is a good website to help you if you haven't done this before: http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/205/Lectures/HOWTO-ERD.html

Comment: I have no idea what is Enhanced relationship diagrams. I will vist your url

Answer (score -1):

A tournament is just a binary tree. You can use a nested set or an adjacency list.

Comment: hm I dont understant you. I have no idea why round robin tournament is binary tree

Comment: It's upside down. The winner is the root. It's important when you have other information.

Comment: but I have no play off here. I have round robin tournament